# php, mysql, and ajax: dynamically display default data, select existing, or add new

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, forms

I am developing a website where a user must choose a (snail)mailing address. I want the the html web form to display the user's default address (from the mysql db). I also want them to be able to choose an alternate address that they have already entered OR to enter a new address.

(Think billing address vs. mailing address, home vs. work address, etc.)

I want the data to display without reloading the page.

I am good with the the PHP, HTML, , and MySQL. It is the JavaScript/AJAX I am having trouble with. I know that the JS/AJAX will call a PHP page that will query the db, JSON encode and return the data. I figure that the part of the form for the address should use a "combo-box" to select saved addresses by a "quickname" or have the option of adding a new address.

I have been looking for a tutorial, example, or reference for such a thing for the past week without any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use JQuery and `$.ajax` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

There are many other methods to use with ajax requests: http://api.jquery.com/?s=.ajax

Answer (score 0):

if you need recive JSON you can use:

```
Example:

Any json that you return in ajax:

{
  "work":true,
  "path":"path/to/file"
}


$.getJSON(url, function(response){
   //Callback ajax..
   console.log(response.work); //true
   console.log(response.path); // path/to/file
});
```